# Inferring by resolution refutation

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I was going through the MIT course [slides](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-825-techniques-in-artificial-intelligence-sma-5504-fall-2002/lecture-notes/Lecture7FinalPart1.pdf), where on page 37 it gives following premises:

> $P\rightarrow Q$
>
> $\lnot P \rightarrow R$

And asks to prove

> $\lnot Q\rightarrow \lnot R$

by resolution refutation.

I tried first, but then failed. So I created the truth table on [this](http://programming.dojo.net.nz/study/truth-table-generator/index) site:
[image]

As can be seem in above picture $\lnot Q\rightarrow \lnot R$ is not TRUE for all values of $P,Q$ and $R$, it means it is not valid. So does the problem itself is wrong? Or I am interpreting it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have verified, you cannot prove it.

With the *truth assignment* $v$ such that :

> $v(P)=v(Q)=$**f** and $v(R)=$**t**

both premises are evaluated to *true* while the conclusion is *false*.

Thus, the conclusion is **not** consequence of the premises.

---

The issue is not that the conclusion "is not TRUE for all values of $P,Q,R$", but that the conclusion is not TRUE in **all** the rows where both premises are (see 2nd row).

Comment: ohhh right, "its about value of conclusion for rows where premises are true but not for all rows" and realised that this problem must have meant to show the conclusion that cannot be derived from the premises, not necessarily incorrect